# Why does batch processing with unusal usage of command SET hang on running in console emulator Cmder?

Tags: batch-file, cmder

I have made a small batch script to generate the MD5 sum of a file. It works great when I remove the line `@echo off`, but hangs on execution in console emulator *Cmder* version 1.1.4.1 when I leave this line.

```
@echo off

if [%1]==[] goto usage

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('certutil -hashfile %1 MD5 ^| find /v "CertUtil" ^| find /v "MD5"') do set output=%%i
set /p =%output: =%<nul >%1.md5

goto :eof

:usage
@echo Usage: %0 FILENAME
exit /b 1
```

If I replace the line `set /p =%output: =%<nul >%1.md5` by `echo %output: =% >%1.md5`, the batch file executed in *Cmder* and not with `cmd.exe` of Windows works, but it outputs an additional newline that I don't want.

What is going on?

**EDIT**: This line doesn't hang on batch processing in *Cmder*:

```
set /p ="Hello" <nul
```

This line hangs on batch processing in *Cmder*:

```
set /p ="Hello" <nul >out
```

Both lines work in a batch file executed by Windows command processor in a command prompt window.

Comment: `@echo off` stops output so you just aren't seeing any output

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb490897.aspx

Comment: Brian, try running the commands and you'll see what I mean by **hangs**

Comment: `set /p ="Hello"` - where's the variable name before `=`?

Comment: @wOxxOm it's a common trick to write a line without linefeed (CR LF), "misusing" `set /p`, not a variable assignment. Works fine without a variablename (surprisingly).

Comment: Cool, thanks. On the topic, apparently some commands hang in the process list, for example `ftp -A localhost|find "something"` hangs most of the time even if I run it in command line interpreter manually.  See if `certutil` process stays in the Task Manager (processes tab).

Comment: See my edit at the end of the question:
This line doesn't hang:

    `set /p ="Hello" <nul`

This line hangs:

    `set /p ="Hello" <nul >out`

Comment: Well, both lines don't hang here, so that's why I think something else is interfering... Try `echo %output: =%` before that line.

Comment: both lines working well too, here. At command line and also in a batchfile.

Comment: @wOxxOm & @Stephan, `set /P` without variable works, but this sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to `1`; so does redirecting nothing `<nul` to `set /P`; to avoid that, provide a dummy variable and pipe something into it, like `echo _| set /P #=` (pipe string `_`, set variable `#`).

Comment: @raphaelh, I think you need to enclose `%1` in between double-quotes: `certutil -hashfile "%1" MD5`; for the second use (redirection), it is not necessary.

Comment: I've found the problem: `set /p ="Hello" <nul >out` works fine in cmd.exe, but in Cmder (1.1.4.1) it hangs.

Comment: @aschipfl With `echo _ | set /p #=Hello >out` there's an extraneous space at the end, whereas with `echo _ | set /p #="Hello" >out` there isn't

Comment: @raphaelh, I was talking about the `>%1.md5` portion only, not the text within the `set /P` command. You're right, `set /P #=Hello>out` produces an extra space, even if you don't state one before the `>`, strangely.